# Node Express Passport with Angular - not compatible?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, passport.js

I'm working on a simple web app running Node/Express on the server using Passport to authenticate via Google, etc. The client is using Angular.

I'm unable to get Angular to play nice with Passport to log into Google though. My setup is like below:

Node/Express/Passport REST endpoint:

```
app.get("/auth/google",
function(req, res, next) {
    passport = req._passport.instance;
    passport.authenticate("google", { scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'] })(req, res, next);
```

});

The client side...

```
myModule.controller("myController", function($q, $scope, $http) {
$scope.loginWithGoogle = function() {
    $http.get("myDomain/auth/google").then(function(response) {
        doStuff();
    });
}
```

...called by a simple:

```
<button ng-click="loginWithGoogle ()">Login</button>
```

The error I'm getting is **'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'myDomain' is therefore not allowed access.'**

However, if I access the REST endpoint directly, by going to myDomain/auth/google in the browser, it works fine. Or I can make a simple HTML `<a href="/auth/google">Login</a>` and get it to work too. So I'm guessing something is going wrong in the wire between my client and server.

I've searched for solutions and could not find any that worked. For instance, I read a suggestion to use $http.jsonp instead of $http.get. That yielded some progress - if a user is already logged into Google (via gmail, other apps, etc.) then they authenticate fine. But if the user isn't already logged into Google, I get an error **'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexepected token <'**. I think this is the HTML that Google is sending back for their login page.

Is there a way I can get Angular to play nice with Node/Express/Passport here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you set the CORS headers in the middleware of your server to allow all domains or at least your client's domain? Also, typo (missing ") in your $http.get

Comment: By CORS headers do you mean:

res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type", "Authorization");

Yes, I've tried them and they didn't change the results I got.

Typo - fixed, thanks. That was due to my edits to hide the real domain.

Comment: [meanjs](http://meanjs.org/) has a nice boilerplate which works off the bat. You just need to insert your API credentials. Perhaps having a look there will point out something missing?

Answer (score 0):

Set your CORS headers everytime while you're sending your response, even if you've handled them in your main file.